# Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException on SharePoint 2010 InfoPath

Tags: infopath, soap

I'm trying to modify my list InfoPath form to connect to a data of a SharePoint Web Service Lists.GetListItems

On the part where I'll specify the parameters, I get the following error:

Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
Root element is missing.

I think my parameters are correct since I got the IDs from SharePoint Manager. What could be causing this error? Thanks

Comment: Care to post the code?

Comment: I dont have a code, Im simply using the InfoPath 2010 wizard on connecting to the web service.
Data > Data Connections > Add... > Receive Data > SOAP > etc...

Comment: The root element is in the returned data. The beginning of the return string ought to be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`. Can you see what the return string is?

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of the Data Connection wizard and the configuration you are using? I'm assuming you are using this to access a list from another site collection?

Answer (score 1):

The quotes from the article [InfoPath: Use SharePoint Web Services](http://wssdev.blogspot.com/2007/06/infopath-use-sharepoint-web-services.html) :

- "Why won't InfoPath work with SharePoint Web Services? It comes down to the fact that InfoPath doesn't recognize that some web services, such as Lists.asmx's GetListItems requires strings (which InfoPath handles just fine) and XmlNodes (which InfoPath can't seem to figure out)"
- "The solution? Create a Proxy Web Service that takes in strings representing the Xml code and create XmlNodes from them"

  Read more there...

Update:
Don't kill the messenger...

The answer of Office365 support in discussion [Has anyone succeeded using webservice in InfoPath on office 365?](http://wssdev.blogspot.com/2007/06/infopath-use-sharepoint-web-services.html) is:

- The root cause of this problem is that "Business Data Connectivity Service" feature is required when trying to get data using web service in InfoPath. However, currently, for security purpose, the Business Data Connectivity Service is not part of the Office 365 SharePoint Online offering. You can find the available features in SharePoint Service Description, which can be found at following link:

  Office 365 for Enterprise Service Descriptions
  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13602

  For a workaround, you may refer to Sky’s suggestion to build an external webservice. If you have any concern about this future, I suggest you submitting a feedback at
  http://mymfe.microsoft.com/Microsoft%20Online%20Services/Feedback.aspx?formID=210

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i am actually trying to create a proxy web service now. However I'm stuck with the disco command. Its giving me an error of "The request failed with http status 401: unauthorize". I tried googling but i found no help. Im rather new to creating a web service, I'm following this walkthrough http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx

Comment: Please open a new question on this. This board is not for discussions but for questions having answers