# The SOAP response indicates that an error occurred on the server

Tags: infopath

When trying to get logged in user details from the AD using GetUserProfileByName for my InfoPath form onload, I am getting the followng error:

The SOAP response indicates that an error occurred on the server:

The User Profile Manager object could not be loaded. ---> No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.

What maybe the cause of this error, or how can I go about fixing it? I've been stuck on this for 2 full days. I've given full control permissions to the user who is executing this, but still i get the same error.

Thanks In advance

Comment: Seems like a duplicate to  (Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException on SharePoint 2010 InfoPath)[http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42342/microsoft-sharepoint-soapserver-soapserverexception-on-sharepoint-2010-infopath)

Comment: Looks like a different exception and different cause to me. Feel free to flag again if you really think these two are identical.

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 SharePoint Online loopback protection is enabled ... what this means is that InfoPath cannot use SharePoint web services such as Lists.asmx.  See the official info from Microsoft here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2674193 NOTE: The documentation does not state what kind of form, so to clarify ... the above reference is for Browser Forms - Forms that open in InfoPath Filler are able to use web services.

You can, however, send items from InfoPath to a SharePoint list using the SharePoint Object Model ... you'll need to be developing on a machine running SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post
http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/02/22/no-user-profile-application-available-mystery-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

It might help fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much guys,, Now its working i couldn't find a way of resolving this issue so i deleted the data connection (GetUserProfileByName)and recreated it again and it is now working perfect

Answer (score 0):

Don't kill the messenger...

The answer of Office365 support in discussion [Has anyone succeeded using webservice in InfoPath on office 365?](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/153/t/11697.aspx) is:

- The root cause of this problem is that "Business Data Connectivity Service" feature is required when trying to get data using web service in InfoPath. However, currently, for security purpose, the Business Data Connectivity Service is not part of the Office 365 SharePoint Online offering. You can find the available features in SharePoint Service Description, which can be found at following link:

  Office 365 for Enterprise Service Descriptions
  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13602

  For a workaround, you may refer to Sky’s suggestion to build an external webservice. If you have any concern about this future, I suggest you submitting a feedback at http://mymfe.microsoft.com/Microsoft%20Online%20Services/Feedback.aspx?formID=210